# How to order in duplicates of 2?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

I have an List, it contains 4 objects. It may contain less or more but always in multiples of 2 i.e. 2, 4, 6 ,8, 10 etc

In my specific case, I have 4 objects inside but they must be treated as pairs and I need to order by them.

I need to order on type which can have a value of 1 or 2. I did try this but it ordered every object one after another, They must be left as pairs.

Hence, the 2 first objects belong to each other and I would like to sort these 2 objects together and then the other 2 objects belong to one another and I would like to sort these 2 objects together.

Here's an example.

```
Name: Apple
Type: 2

Name: Orange
Type: 1

Name: Pear
Type: 2

Name: Peach
Type: 1
```

When I would like to obtain is a list like so. Notice the orange and apple have changed positions as the sort was done on this pair. And so has the pear and the peach.

```
Name: Orange
Type: 1

Name: Apple
Type: 2

Name: Peach
Type: 1

Name: Pear
Type: 2
```

Here is an example of my sort, that of course is wrong.

I have tried a number of ways but of course I keep getting, 1's first and then 2's because its not taking into consideration that I want to sort in pairs.

```
var wrongSort = myList.Select(x => x.Items).OrderBy(x => x.Type).ToList();
```

Of course "myList" is a standard collection inside which is a list of Items. The list of items is what I want to order by in pairs.

### Edit

With regards to using Tuples, this could work but the list is passed to me as a standard collection and I still need a standard list at the end. Tuples really wouldn't work here.

The collection is used in a `foreach` iteration so the order is important.

Comment: If they are pairs, why don't you put the two items in a single wrapper? So you can have a FruitPair class or use a Tuple if that's easier for you.

Comment: The List is not returned to me as a tuple and I still need a standard collection at the end.. But I need to sort pairs 2 x 2. if that makes sense.

Comment: The List I have is the perfect format I have but in the wrong order. The list is being used in an iteration of a foreach.

Comment: @Martin No, it's not in the perfect format.  If someone gave you this data in such an unmanagable format you should take the time to parse it into a real type, and *then* you can worry about sorting it.

Comment: I'm not sure why you feel that using a new type would prevent you from using a foreach loop or doing whatever you want with the data later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can project the list to a new list that includes the position in the list, then order by the "group number" first:

```
myList.Select((f,i) => new {f, i})  // add the position in the list
      .OrderBy(fi => fi.i / n)      // "groups" into n items (2, 4, etc.)
      .ThenBy(fi => fi.f.Type)      // orders within each group by the Type
      .Select (fi => fi.f)          // removes the added index
```

Comment: Great D Stanley, That works.. I think the OrderBy and dividing by 2 means do it in pairs.. Can you explain more. I have never sene OrderBy used like that...  thanks